# Customized scroll with jquery not working on edge and IE.?

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

Can someone help me why this does not scroll on edge or IE

```js
/*! Copyright (c) 2011 Piotr Rochala (http://rocha.la)
 * Dual licensed under the MIT (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php)
 * and GPL (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/gpl-license.php) licenses.
 *
 * Version: 0.2.5
 * 
 */
(function($) {

  jQuery.fn.extend({
    slimScroll: function(o) {

      var ops = o;
      //do it for every element that matches selector
      this.each(function() {

        var isOverPanel, isOverBar, isDragg, queueHide, barHeight,
          divS = '<div></div>',
          minBarHeight = 30,
          wheelStep = 30,
          o = ops || {},
          cwidth = o.width || 'auto',
          cheight = o.height || '250px',
          size = o.size || '7px',
          color = o.color || '#000',
          position = o.position || 'right',
          opacity = o.opacity || .4,
          alwaysVisible = o.alwaysVisible === true;

        //used in event handlers and for better minification
        var me = $(this);

        //wrap content
        var wrapper = $(divS).css({
          position: 'relative',
          overflow: 'hidden',
          width: cwidth,
          height: cheight
        }).attr({
          'class': 'slimScrollDiv'
        });

        //update style for the div
        me.css({
          overflow: 'hidden',
          width: cwidth,
          height: cheight
        });

        //create scrollbar rail
        var rail = $(divS).css({
          width: '15px',
          height: '100%',
          position: 'absolute',
          top: 0
        });

        //create scrollbar
        var bar = $(divS).attr({
          'class': 'slimScrollBar ',
          style: 'border-radius: ' + size
        }).css({
          background: color,
          width: size,
          position: 'absolute',
          top: 0,
          opacity: opacity,
          display: alwaysVisible ? 'block' : 'none',
          BorderRadius: size,
          MozBorderRadius: size,
          WebkitBorderRadius: size,
          zIndex: 99
        });

        //set position
        var posCss = (position == 'right') ? {
          right: '1px'
        } : {
          left: '1px'
        };
        rail.css(posCss);
        bar.css(posCss);

        //wrap it
        me.wrap(wrapper);

        //append to parent div
        me.parent().append(bar);
        me.parent().append(rail);

        //make it draggable
        bar.draggable({
          axis: 'y',
          containment: 'parent',
          start: function() {
            isDragg = true;
          },
          stop: function() {
            isDragg = false;
            hideBar();
          },
          drag: function(e) {
            //scroll content
            scrollContent(0, $(this).position().top, false);
          }
        });

        //on rail over
        rail.hover(function() {
          showBar();
        }, function() {
          hideBar();
        });

        //on bar over
        bar.hover(function() {
          isOverBar = true;
        }, function() {
          isOverBar = false;
        });

        //show on parent mouseover
        me.hover(function() {
          isOverPanel = true;
          showBar();
          hideBar();
        }, function() {
          isOverPanel = false;
          hideBar();
        });

        var _onWheel = function(e) {
          //use mouse wheel only when mouse is over
          if (!isOverPanel) {
            return;
          }

          var e = e || window.event;

          var delta = 0;
          if (e.wheelDelta) {
            delta = -e.wheelDelta / 120;
          }
          if (e.detail) {
            delta = e.detail / 3;
          }

          //scroll content
          scrollContent(0, delta, true);

          //stop window scroll
          if (e.preventDefault) {
            e.preventDefault();
          }
          e.returnValue = false;
        }

        var scrollContent = function(x, y, isWheel) {
          var delta = y;

          if (isWheel) {
            //move bar with mouse wheel
            delta = bar.position().top + y * wheelStep;

            //move bar, make sure it doesn't go out
            delta = Math.max(delta, 0);
            var maxTop = me.outerHeight() - bar.outerHeight();
            delta = Math.min(delta, maxTop);

            //scroll the scrollbar
            bar.css({
              top: delta + 'px'
            });
          }

          //calculate actual scroll amount
          percentScroll = parseInt(bar.position().top) / (me.outerHeight() - bar.outerHeight());
          delta = percentScroll * (me[0].scrollHeight - me.outerHeight());

          //scroll content
          me.scrollTop(delta);

          //ensure bar is visible
          showBar();
        }

        var attachWheel = function() {
          if (window.addEventListener) {
            this.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', _onWheel, false);
            this.addEventListener('mousewheel', _onWheel, false);
          } else {
            document.attachEvent("onmousewheel", _onWheel)
          }
        }

        //attach scroll events
        attachWheel();

        var getBarHeight = function() {
          //calculate scrollbar height and make sure it is not too small
          barHeight = Math.max((me.outerHeight() / me[0].scrollHeight) * me.outerHeight(), minBarHeight);
          bar.css({
            height: barHeight + 'px'
          });
        }

        //set up initial height
        getBarHeight();

        var showBar = function() {
          //recalculate bar height
          getBarHeight();
          clearTimeout(queueHide);

          //show only when required
          if (barHeight >= me.outerHeight()) {
            return;
          }
          bar.fadeIn('fast');
        }

        var hideBar = function() {
          //only hide when options allow it
          if (!alwaysVisible) {
            queueHide = setTimeout(function() {
              if (!isOverBar && !isDragg) {
                bar.fadeOut('slow');
              }
            }, 1000);
          }
        }

      });

      //maintain chainability
      return this;
    }
  });

  jQuery.fn.extend({
    slimscroll: jQuery.fn.slimScroll
  });

})(jQuery);


//invalid name call
$('#chatlist').slimscroll({
  color: '#00f',
  size: '10px',
  width: '50px',
  height: '50px'
});
```

```css
div#chatlist {
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px!important;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div.mousescroll {
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.mousescroll:hover {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.slimScrollDiv {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div id="chatlist" class="mousescroll">
  <ul>
    <li>1 item</li>
    <li>2 item</li>
    <li>3 item</li>
    <li>4 item</li>
    <li>5 item</li>
    <li>6 item</li>
    <li>7 item</li>
    <li>8 tem</li>
    <li>9 item</li>
    <li>a item</li>
    <li>b item</li>
    <li>c item</li>
    <li>d item</li>
    <li>e item</li>
    <li>f item</li>
    <li>g item</li>
    <li>h item</li>
    <li>i item</li>
    <li>j item</li>
    <li>k item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Is there something wrong with a function or what can it be, can someone help me please I am new on coding and I dont understand this things very clearly maybe you understand that, What can it be..?     Is there something wrong with a function or what can it be, can someone help me please I am new on coding and I dont understand this things very clearly maybe you understand that, What can it be..?

Comment: yes mousescroll it works on chrome and mozilla but on edge and internet explorer does not work

Comment: You said chrome did not work in the title

Comment: sorry I meant on chrome works

Answer (score 0):

I try to make a test with your code in Chrome, IE and MS Edge.

I find that scroll is working fine with MS Edge and IE.

Below are my testing results.

Output in Chrome:

[image]

Output in MS Edge:

[image]

Output in IE:

[image]

I suggest you to only make a test with your above code and check whether it is working or not. If issue persist than try to check the console for any error or warning message.